# Can I display likes, views etc. on my website

Tags: youtube-api

Can I display likes, views, video post date, etc. on my website with each embedded YouTube video?
At the moment I just embed the video with an Iframe in my html code of my website, but  I would like some stats or even a video search function on the website. Thanks for taking the time to read this.